# ERROR: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in Downloads.jl

Tags: julia

I'm trying to download a `.xlsx` file using Julia by [`Downloads.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Downloads.jl) like this, But I get an error:

```
julia> using Downloads: download

julia> file = download("http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/IntraDayPrice.aspx?i=35425587644337450&m=30")
ERROR: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden while requesting http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/IntraDayPrice.aspx?i=35425587644337450&m=30
Stacktrace:
 [1] #3
   @ C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\juliaup\julia-1.8.0+0.x64\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Downloads\src\Downloads.jl:243 [inlined]
 [2] arg_write(f::Downloads.var"#3#4"{Nothing, Vector{Pair{String, String}}, Float64, Nothing, Bool, Nothing, Nothing, String}, arg::Nothing)
   @ ArgTools C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\juliaup\julia-1.8.0+0.x64\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\ArgTools\src\ArgTools.jl:123
 [3] #download#2
   @ C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\juliaup\julia-1.8.0+0.x64\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Downloads\src\Downloads.jl:230 [inlined]
 [4] download (repeats 2 times)
   @ C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\juliaup\julia-1.8.0+0.x64\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Downloads\src\Downloads.jl:219 [inlined]
 [5] top-level scope
   @ REPL[8]:1
```

I don't know where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is weird. It works using `HTTP.download`, but the resulting file is broken somehow.

Comment: @phipsgabler Yes, I tried HTTP, but it didn't work. However, one of my friends tried `res = HTTP.get("<THE_LINK>")` and then `write("<PATH>/file.xlsx", res.body);` and finally `a = XLSX.readxlsx("<THE_PATH>/file.xlsx")` and this works for him without any problem! I can't understand why! I guess there is something with encoding, maybe. for me, the `XLSX.readxlsx(...)` throws `ERROR: <PATH>/file.xlsx is not a valid XLSX file.`.

Comment: Funny. It also works using httpie. Looks like a bug to me, try reporting an issue for HTTP.jl, with the output of `HTTP.get(..., verbose=3)`.

Comment: @phipsgabler this `file = HTTP.get("<THE_LINK>");` and then `write("<PATH>/file.csv.gz", file.body)` downloads and writes the file correctly. But I don't know how to read the `xlsx` file contained in the `gz` file.